# C# Http slower than browser (PostMan) - any ideas?

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

**Completely updated** based on comments and more tests.

I'm calling a web-service via HTTP POST using PostMan (Chrome extension). Doing the same via C# is slower. Why, I don't know. Maybe there's nothing to be done.

The response-time with browser (PostMan) is about 70 ms every time.
I've done different versions in C#:

- `HttpClient` (and even reusing the same HttpClient, calling 2x in a row, just measuring the time for the 2nd call as suggested in comments). Time 150ms best case, often 170 ms. This is for the 2nd call actually, not including creating an instance. Just POST and DL of answer. Using await on both upload (the POST body) and download of response, even if that really doesn't matter for this test.
- `WebClient`, not including instatiating the client, just the post request and the response, no parsing, just converting from bytes to string, 160ms.
- Raw transfer test, just to check the transfer/overhead on my local machine, which in any case is not measured: about 10 ms.
- Using other clients based on `HttpWebRequest` (ServiceStack v4's JsonServiceClient): About the same.

I've already tried including

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
System.Net.ServicePointManager.MaxServicePoints = 200;
```

but the result is the same.

**So is the answer just that Chrome (which Postman builds on) is just better optimized than .NET, or is there something one can do?**

*PS: Yes, I know this might look more like a discussion than Q&A, but I'm looking for an answer, so in that sense it's a question.*

Comment: Any reason you're not calling the methods asynchronously? I find the lack of `await` disturbing.

Comment: I don't see a question here...

Comment: I agree with @Nasreddine, either switch to [`WebClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx) or use the async methods correctly.

Comment: Have you tried not creating a fresh instance of HttpClient for each call? Typically you only need one client for standard use cases.

Comment: I have updated my non-question question. How can I optimize. Why is vanilla .NET so slow here? I will claim async is not the magic bullet - it will increase throughput, getting more requests per second, for a server, but assume this is a client - where does the time go, and how to optimize it?

Comment: @specimen using async will not speed up your request, so it's irrelevant for your question. It is important for clients as it does not block the calling thread and therefore the message pump in a message driven environment. Have you tried making the same request multiple times with a cached HttpClient instance? Subsequent calls should be faster than the first one as the connection stays open.